Is the composition of the Cerebrospinal Fluid (CSF) in the first two ventricles different than that in the third and fourth ones?
We know two things. The first is that Cerebrospinal Fluid (CSF) flows from the first and second ventricles down to the third and then fourth ones https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cerebrospinal_fluid#Circulation . And the second is that the Blood–Brain Barrier (BBB) only protects the two first ventricles https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood%E2%80%93brain_barrier#Structure , because part of the blood vessels around the two lower ventricles aren't covered with the BBB.
From this it seems to follow, that certain molecules enter the lower ventricles and never arrive in the first two. The first two ventricles are more protected.
An example of a theoretical consequence would be that if there is some reason to deliver some medicine to the third ventricle, and that medicine won't pass through the BBB, it could still be used because it would get there. But if the medicine needs to get to the first ventricles, it won't make it there.
Am I correct?
